# Automatically calculate length of line + alignment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand*\mlr{\hspace{6em}}

\newcommand*\addition[4]{%
\begin{array}{@{} r @{,} l @{}}
                   #1 & #2 \\
  + \hspace{0.2em} #3 & #4 \\
  \hline
\end{array}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\addition{1}{14}{14}{3}
\mlr
\addition{1}{2}{1}{3}
\mlr
\addition{20}{1}{2}{17}
\mlr
\addition{5}{9}{2}{7}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Questions**

- In the third sum I would like the `+` sign to be aligned to the left of `20.1` (not underneath the `2` in `20.1`). In general I would the plus sign to be aligned to the left of the number with the most digits in the interger part.
- How to I get a double underline one `\baselineskip` after the `\hline` with the same length as the `\hline`? I would like the double underline to be drawn with the correct length automatically. (I know that I can manually correct this using `\hphantom`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allocate a column for the `+` sign, it's that easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\addition[4]{%
\begin{array}{@{} r@{} r @{,} l @{}}
   & #1 & #2 \\
 + & #3 & #4 \\
 \hline
 \\
 \hline\hline
\end{array}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\addition{1}{14}{14}{3}
\qquad
\addition{1}{2}{1}{3}
\qquad
\addition{20}{1}{2}{17}
\qquad
\addition{5}{9}{2}{7}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

A different implementation with [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), where the first argument specifies the number of digits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addition}{mmm}{%
  \begin{array}{@{} r@{\,} S[table-format=#1] @{}}
    & #2 \\
  + & #3 \\
  \hline
  \\
  \hline\hline
  \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\addition{2.2}{1,14}{14,3}
\qquad
\addition{1.1}{1,2}{1,3}
\qquad
\addition{2.2}{20,1}{2,17}
\qquad
\addition{2.0}{59}{27}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some more work we can avoid the need to specify the number of digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addition}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_svend_sum_first_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_svend_sum_first_tl { . } { , }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_svend_sum_second_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_svend_sum_second_tl { . } { , }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_svend_sum_first_seq { , } \l_svend_sum_first_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_svend_sum_second_seq { , } \l_svend_sum_second_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_svend_sum_first_tl
   {
    \int_to_arabic:f
     {
      \int_max:nn
       { \tl_count:f { \seq_item:Nn \l_svend_sum_first_seq { 1 } } }
       { \tl_count:f { \seq_item:Nn \l_svend_sum_second_seq { 1 } } }
     }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_svend_sum_second_tl
   {
    \int_to_arabic:f
     {
      \int_max:nn
       { \tl_count:f { \seq_item:Nn \l_svend_sum_first_seq { 2 } } }
       { \tl_count:f { \seq_item:Nn \l_svend_sum_second_seq { 2 } } }
     }
   }
  \begin{array}{@{} r@{\,} S[table-format=\l_svend_sum_first_tl.\l_svend_sum_second_tl] @{}}
    & #1 \\
  + & #2 \\
  \hline
  \\
  \hline\hline
  \end{array}%
}
\tl_new:N \l_svend_sum_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_svend_sum_second_tl
\seq_new:N \l_svend_sum_first_seq
\seq_new:N \l_svend_sum_second_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_to_arabic:n { f }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\addition{1,14}{14,3}
\qquad
\addition{1,2}{1,3}
\qquad
\addition{20,1}{2,17}
\qquad
\addition{59}{27}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Comment: I hadn't tested the code at the bottom of your answer when I accepted it; when I compile it, I get the error `> \l_svend_sum_first_tl=2.
<recently read> }
                 
l.54 \addition{1,14}{14,3}`. P.S. When it is fixed, I'll accept your answer again.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sorry, I forgot to remove the debugging functions.